# Weird behavior when accessing request.user in django

Tags: django

I have a simple view which requires a user to be logged in AND belongs to a specific group as the following

```
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = IndexSerializer

    def test_func(self):
        print(self.request.user) // User object
        return self.request.user.groups.filter(name='Poster').exists()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.request.user) // AnonymousUser
        print(request.user) // Anonymous User
        return HttpResponse('Welcome')
```

The thing is when I print the user inside the get method it returns AnonymousUser but it returns a User object inside the test_func method. I am clueless of why this is happening so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to call the test-func inside the get function? See what it returns.

Comment: @Chymdy This returns an AnonymousUser as well.

Comment: Well then, its settled. You simply aren't logged in on when you call your get function.

Comment: seems like you are using [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), if so, you need to look at [authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) and [permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

Comment: @JPG Thank you, turns out I was missing out the "Token" word before providing the actual token!. Adding Authorization: Token "Token here" solved my problem.

Comment: Okay, Great. But, you don't need `LoginRequiredMixin` and `UserPassesTestMixin` since you are using DRF